# When was the first time the Daleks moved the earth?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

I was re-watching series 4's The Stolen Earth, and the Doctor mentioned: "someone tried to move the earth once before, a long time ago." Then it cuts to the Daleks, implying that it was they who attempted this. Does anyone know if there's a comic or episode about this? Or was this simply an offhand comment?

Comment: Dalek 1 to Dalek 2: "IMPREGNATE!!! DID THE EARTH MOVE FOR YOU?"

Answer (score 3):

According to the Tardis Data Core/Doctor Who Wiki, this is a reference to the Second Season serial [*The Dalek Invasion of Earth*](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Dalek_Invasion_of_Earth_(TV_story)), broadcast November-December 1964: ***The Doctor mentions that someone tried to move the Earth "a long time ago." The Daleks once tried to place a drive system into the centre of the Earth so that they could pilot the planet.***

The wiki also notes that the Time Lords *did* actually move the Earth in the 23rd Season of the show, more commonly referred to as [*The Trial of a Time Lord*](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Season_23): ***The Time Lords successfully relocated the Earth, causing it to become known as Ravolox.***